# vtk LNK error in vtkRenderingOpenGL2-8.2.lib

Tags: vtk

I encountered an error while using vtk 8.2.0.
I ran the code below and got the following error:

```
vtkRenderingOpenGL2-8.2.lib(vtkOpenGLState.obj) : error LNK2019: __imp_SymGetLineFromAddr64   .......
```

```
#include <vtkAutoInit.h>
VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkInteractionStyle)
VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkRenderingOpenGL2)
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

If someone has any solution please help me.

Comment: I also encountered same issue when using VTK 8.2.0 which is static Build. Are you able to resolve this issue ?

Comment: This issue was resolved by adding and linking the Opengl32.lib library from the windows SDK.  x86 and x64 versions of this library must not be mixed.